# Is clip or part of a clip used?

Tags: premiere

Working in PremierePro CC.
70 hours of footage (shot over several months).
6 hours of finals (60 episodes in total), each done in separate Premiere project.

Problem:
Around 60 hours of footage is left unused, which can be used for another project but can not find an easy way to pull out unused clips.

I know how to use Premiere option for duplicate clips, but this option works fine only on small projects.

Is there a software that would grab all the finals and all the clips and do a comparison, and mark out clips (or part of the clips) that are left unused.

Answer (score 1):

*(Just in case you don't want to have to watch a two and a half minute "tutorial" containing about ten seconds worth of useful information)*

There is a column in your project window that shows how many times an item is used.

[image]

**It's not visible by default**, you can make it so by right-clicking the column headers and choosing *Metadata Display*, then ticking Audio/Video usage in the *Premiere Pro Project Metadata* folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's ready man.
Watch the tutorial that I've created:

Comment: Can you add some details about the steps in your answer?  Link only answers are of extremely limited value as they are dependent on the link to remain active or the answer becomes useless.  Tutorial videos are great for being easy to understand, but providing basic steps in text will turn this in to a much better answer.